# Nested gitlab submodules

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules

I have three gitlab repositories (this is just a simplification of my real problem):

- RepoResources: A repository containing resources.
- RepoLibrary: A repository containing class library projects that make use of the resources (referenced as a submodule).
- RepoApp: A repository containing application projects that make direct use of both the RepoLibrary and the RepoResources (referenced as submodules).

My intention is to get RepoLibrary and RepoResources when I clone RepoLibrary (which happens):

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║ RepoLibrary       ║
╚═══════════════════╝
      │
      │
      V
╔═══════════════════╗
║ RepoResources     ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

But I also want to get each repository just once when I clone RepoApp:

```
╔════════════════╗     ╔═══════════════════╗
║ RepoApp        ║────>║ RepoLibrary       ║
╚════════════════╝     ╚═══════════════════╝
               │          │
               │          │
               V          V
          ╔═══════════════════╗
          ║ RepoResources     ║
          ╚═══════════════════╝
```

However, what I get is this, with RepoResources downloaded twice (and, possibly, up to different commits):

```
╔═══════════════════╗        ╔═══════════════════╗
║ RepoApp           ║───────>║ RepoLibrary       ║
╚═══════════════════╝        ╚═══════════════════╝
            │                     │
            │                     │
            V                     V
╔═══════════════════╗        ╔═══════════════════╗
║ RepoResources     ║        ║ RepoResources     ║
╚═══════════════════╝        ╚═══════════════════╝
```

In order to solve this, I am considering going from multi to monorepo. But I would prefer to have multiple repositories.

Do you have any suggestions on how to set this up?

Thank you.

[Diagram of my actual repositories and dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9mAt.png)